# c# Remove parts of string from label inside an datalist

Tags: c#, label, datalist

Im working on a small news applicaton and im trying to remove parts of a text from a label inside a datalist, here is my code

```
<asp:DataListID="itemListNews"runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>      
            <div class="news">
                <span class="news-author"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"author") %></span>
                <asp:Label ID="lbTest" runat="server" class="news-text"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"news") %></asp:Label>
            </div>   
       </ItemTemplate>
```

I have been trying a couple of things and i keep getting the error message: `startIndex must be less than the length of the string.Parameter name: startIndex`

```
foreach (DataListItem item in itemListNews.Items)
    {
        Label lbtest = (Label) item.FindControl("lbTest");
        lbtest.Text.Remove(10);    
    }
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Are *some* strings in the list shorter than 10 characters?

Comment: No the strings are about 30-100 characters, and i only want to show the first 10 charactres of the string

Answer (score 2):

First you should test your string size is bigger than 10, Also at last assign new value:

```
if (lbtest.Text != null && lbtest.Text.Length > 10)
{
  lbtest.Text = lbtest.Text.Remove(10);
}
```

Doing just `lbtest.Text.Remove(10);` doesn't do anything (`string` is immutable, so you should reassign it).

Comment: The strings are still the same length trying this. But i dont get an error tho

Comment: @dumbel, Sure there are some string with length smaller or equal to 10, you can find them by changing the `>10` to `<=10` to find them.